# What makes Night Elves flip when jumping in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there some timing associated with Night Elves jump-flipping?  Or is it just random?

Comment: Only when it would make the Night Elf look *badass*.

Comment: @Brant: If that were the case, Night Elves would never flip.

Answer (score 8):

About a 1/5 chance for them to do a flip. Completely random. Blood elves spin are about half the chance.

Answer (score 3):

It's just random. I've seen speculation of somewhere between a 10 and 20% chance.

Comment: Hm. I heard something indicating that it was based on which frame of the running animation your character was on...

Comment: @Raven If that was true, you wouldn't be able to flip from a complete standstill. Which is absolutely possible.

Comment: touche.

Comment: You could then just say it's based on a frame of the "standing still" animation then. :P  Still totally random

Answer (score 0):

A night elf flip is indeed at random, some people have found ways to actually flip every single time, but it's not a guarantee that you will actually flip everytime unless you get it spot on. You can flip every time if you watch your feet. Once your right foot touches the ground and hasn't gone off yet, jump, and you should have succeeded if you did it right. Another way is, if you are going down a hill, and at the point at which the hill starts to lower how steep it is, jump. These are the ways I have discovered.

Answer (score -3):

I have been fiddling. If you time it with the right foot you have a higher chance, I managed four in a row when trying this. Then after another three, and it works best when the right foot is either just hitting the ground or leaving the ground. I think its to do with the animation. People generally flip from their preferred foot.